# Reverting back to a specific changes after saving in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

In my project in Visual Studio 2019, I opened a file and made some changes. After running it, I decided to undo(ctrl + z) my changes and revert it back to the original point where I opened it and do some other code again to verify my changes. After saving and running my code, I decided to revert it back to the point where I made my first changes. And now, I cannot revert it back anymore. I tried to search it online but had no luck. Is there a way to revert my first changes back? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-Y is Redo, which is the opposite of Ctrl-Z Undo.

I would suggest creating a Git repository. You can commit versions of your code and revert to any of your previous versions.